# Discrete Mathematics Refreshers Course?

Tags: math

I graduated 8 years ago and did a discrete mathematics course in my 2nd year, but I've been told that I'll likely be asked discrete maths questions in an upcoming interview.

Is there a simple webpage/document that I can use to refresh my memory? I understood the concepts when I took the course 10 odd years ago, but my memory is a bit rusty and I'd like to just refresh it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Discrete Math](http://www.freetechbooks.com/discrete-mathematics-f65.html) section of freetechbooks.com. Those books are free (all of them gratis and most also free as in freedom) and you have different options; from short class-style discrete math textbooks which are full of exercises, to more programming-oriented discrete math books.

Comment: Why?  What's good about it?  Please expand your answer.

Comment: @Walter I tried to expand it a little bit. Thanks for the suggestion